# How do I get chrome.tabs.update to redirect to a url?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

In my chrome extension, I am trying to get my second tab to redirect to another URL. Does anyone have a working example of chrome.tabs.update they can share?

I am trying with a code like this:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: tab.url, selected: true});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to redirect newtab to a url you can use this [sample code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/override/override_igoogle.zip).Just change the url you want the new tab to redirect to.
Even if you want to use update method use this: chrome.tabs.update({url: "http://example.com"});